# Unable to select menu item using xpath [Validates in Xpath checker, but webdriver cannot find it]

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to select a menu item...though xpath validates well in Xpath checker, it does not work from WebDriver ...can someone help?

I get *Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(),'Start Loan Process')]"}*

```
HMTL looks something like this
<div class="bd">
<ul class="first-of-type">
<li id="yui-gen7" class="yuimenuitem first-of-type" groupindex="0" index="0">
<li id="yui-gen8" class="yuimenuitem" groupindex="0" index="1">
<li id="yui-gen9" class="yuimenuitem" groupindex="0" index="2">
<li id="yui-gen10" class="yuimenuitem" groupindex="0" index="3">
<li id="yui-gen11" class="yuimenuitem" groupindex="0" index="4">
<a class="yuimenuitemlabel" href="#">Start Loan Process</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the other hand you can also try to use findElementsBy(By.classname("yuimenuitemlabel")) 
Get them to list of web elements and then filter it using webelement.getText() method.

Answer (score 2):

I have had very little luck with using the `Text()` part of the xpath. I would rather use the `.Text` (C#) or `.getText()` (java) method.

This is how i would write this in c#:
`driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//*/a").Text.Contains("Start Loan Process");`

The xpath part is of course debateable. It could also be: `".//div/li/a"`. You can use what you want.